# TDS7 Login packet, encrypted password

Tags: authentication, passwords

who knows how the password is encrypted in tds7 login packet? How can I decode it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25PvT.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it isn't encrypted, it's encoded. I am not sure how to decode it manually. HOWEVER, if you have a saved PCAP of the traffic, you can open the PCAP in NetworkMiner (part of the Security Onion Linux distro). Open the PCAP in NetworkMiner and click on the Credentials tab. You will see the username and the automatically decoded password listed.